# “is not defined” in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i'm working on a Single page Application using Vuejs and Nuxtjs and i want to add a external js file to my project
i added the below code to my nuxt.config.js file

```
script: [
  { src: '****/wialon.js', body: true }
]
```

and in the default.vue file in `mounted()` this code

```
mounted () {
  wialon.core.Session.getInstance().initSession('***') // init session
}
```

and i got this error when i npm run dev

> 'wialon' is not defined

but when i try to build this app (npm run build) and copy the files to my server or local host it is working!!

can you please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: link to  https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2819